# Why is an algorithm complexity given in the Big O notation instead of Theta?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I know what the Big O, Theta and Omega notations are, but for example, if my algorithm is a for inside of a for, looping n times, my complexity would be O(n²), but why O(n²) instead of ϴ(n²)? Since the complexity IS in fact O(n²) and Ω(n²), then it would also be ϴ(n²), and I just can't see any reason to not use ϴ(n²) instead of O(n²), since ϴ(n²) restricts my complexity with an upper and bottom value, not only upper in the case of O(n²).

Comment: I am voting to close as opinion based.

Comment: I am literally asking why it is like that, I sincerely don't know and wish to know why don't people use Theta instead of Big O. I'm a computer science student and don't have my professor available since we're having online classes, and really wish to know that...

Comment: Not every problem has a known lower bound, it is more convenient to use upper bound as "worst case". In computational complexity theory they focus on classifying problems that are more complicated than a nested for loop, and one way of solving things is showing that problem A is at least as hard as problem B, giving a lower bound and vise versa. Sometimes the upper and lower bounds are not the same as well.

Comment: Could you give me an example of a problem that doesn't have a lower bound? I can't think of one. Also, would I be wrong if instead of using O() in my (simple) complexities, I started to use ϴ(), since that would be technically more precise, if of course my algorithm complexities have a lower bound.

Comment: No you can't use `ϴ` instead of `O`.

Comment: Not even if it is true? For example, a for inside a for, that would be O(n²) and ϴ(n²), so it would be more precise to use ϴ, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221787/discussion-between-diego-vinicius-and-tony-tannous).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` then `f(n) = O(g(n))`. This because `Θ(g(n)) ⊆ O (g(n))`.

In your specific case if a loop runs **exactly** `n^2` time the time complexity is in both `O(n^2)` and `Θ(n^2)`.
The main reason why big-O is typically enough is that we are more interested in the worst case time complexity when analyzing the algorithm's performance, and knowing the worst case scenario is usually enough.
Also, not always is possible to find a tight bound.

Comment: That was what another user said in the comments as well, thank you!